# R how does a matrix gets distributed when using mcLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a matrix of 1000 rows and 16 columns. The first 8 columns represent one sample and remaining 8 columns represent another sample. For each of 1000 rows I need to calculate the ration of  mean of first 8 columns and mean of last 8 columns. How can I perform this using mcLapply?

So far this is what I have:

```
library(parallel)

data <- a matrix of size 1000x16

mclapply(data, function(x){ 
                            mean(x[,1:8])/mean(x[,9:16])
                          }, mc.cores = detectCores())
```

I get the following error:
error in x[, 1:8] : incorrect number of dimensions\n'

Thanks

Comment: `mclapply()` works just like `lapply()` in this sense, so skip the parallelization for now and focus on how to do it with `lapply()`.  Then it should work with `mclapply()`.  If you find that there's another base R apply function that does what you need, then you can find parallel versions of those in the [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply) package.  But again, figure out how to do it without parallelization first.

Answer (score 1):

With `lapply`, the `data` matrix is treated as a vector and in each iteration, `x` is a single number from `data`. You can see this with the following example:

```
library(parallel)

x <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
mclapply(x, print, mc.cores = 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4
```

That's why you got incorrect dimension error. I guess what you wanted is:

```
rowMeans(data[,1:8])/rowMeans(data[,9:16])
```

---

If you have to use `mclapply`, you can loop over row numbers:

```
mclapply(1:nrow(data), function(x){ 
    mean(data[x,1:8])/mean(data[x,9:16])
}, mc.cores = detectCores())
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting incorrect dimensions when I try the following: library(parallel)

x <- matrix(1:8, nrow = 2)
x
mclapply(x, function(x){ 
                          rowMeans(x[,1:2])/rowMeans(x[,3:4])
                          }, mc.cores = detectCores()) I have to use parallel and mcLapply to measure the performance in various implementations.

Comment: @SpaceX, you do not need to use mclapply here. `rowMeans` is a vectorized function and it is much faster than lapply or mclapply for your case. And see the edit if you insist.